# What to do to be able to add links?

Tags: facebook, sdk, tabs

Have a problem. 
I create app, which allows you to add a page tab.
Use facebook dialog add Page tab.
What I would not use links, redirect uri move to link, which is entered in the application settings "Page Tab".
What to do to be able to add links ?
Example:
If in app settings "test.com", I can add tab link "test.com/test/index.html"

Comment: can you show your codes ?

Answer (score 0):

This is the code:

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
FB.init({
    appId      : '...',
    status     : true,
    cookie     : true,
    xfbml      : true  
});

$(document).trigger('fbload');  //  <---- THIS RIGHT HERE TRIGGERS A CUSTOM EVENT CALLED 'fbload'
};

function addToPage(url) {
// calling the API ...
var obj = {
    method: 'pagetab',
    redirect_uri: url
};

FB.ui(obj, function(response){
    if (response != null && response.tabs_added != null) {
        //response.tabs_added will have an array with the ids of the tabs selected by the user
    }
});
}

var user_form_link = splitted[0]+'forms/'+uid+'.html';
addToPage(user_form_link);
```